# How to replace URLs from html to a file using grep, sed or any common tools?

Tags: bash, scripts, grep, sed, html

I'm trying to replace URLs of my `conf` file from a HTML file because sometimes the URLs get updated/changed. I need a simple script that can fetch the HTML & update/replace the URLs in my `conf` file. I'm new in Ubuntu/Linux.

Edit: The HTML file gets changed by the server admin where I don't have any access. I can only visit the up-to-date site by using below `Html Location` & update my conf file manually.

Html Location: `https://10.10.10.1`

Part of HTML file:

```
<li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hvr-bounce-to-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Movies<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        
<li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="http://10.10.10.7/MY-FTP-2/English%20Movies/">English Movies</a></li>
<li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="http://10.10.10.8/MY-FTP-1/English%20Movies%20%281080p%29/">English Movies -1080p </a></li>
                                        
                                        <li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="http://10.10.10.9/MY-FTP-1/Hindi%20Movies/">Hindi Movies</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="http://10.10.10.8/MY-FTP-1/SOUTH%20INDIAN%20MOVIES/Hindi%20Dubbed/">South-Movie Hindi Dubbed</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="http://10.10.10.10/MY-FTP-3/Animation%20Movies/">Animation Movies</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" href="http://10.10.10.10/MY-FTP-3/Animation%20Movies%20%281080p%29/">Animation Movies -1080p</a></li>
```

After getting the HTML, it will replace/update the links in my rclone.conf file.

`rclone.conf` file preview:

```
[Hindi Movies]
type = http
url = http://10.10.10.9/MY-FTP-1/Hindi%20Movies/

[English Movies]
type = http
url = http://10.10.10.7/MY-FTP-2/English%20Movies/

[English Movies -1080p]
type = http
url = http://10.10.10.9/MY-FTP-1/English%20Movies%20%281080p%29/

[South-Movie Hindi Dubbed]
type = http
url = http://10.10.10.9/MY-FTP-1/SOUTH%20INDIAN%20MOVIES/Hindi%20Dubbed/

[Animation Movies]
type = http
url = http://10.10.10.10/MY-FTP-3/Animation%20Movies/

[Animation Movies -1080p]
type = http
url = http://10.10.10.10/MY-FTP-3/Animation%20Movies%20%281080p%29/
```

So I've written a noob script that will start the work but it seems it's giving me an error !

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Fetch the HTML from the website
html = requests.get("http://10.10.10.1/")

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

# The location of the rclone.conf file
rclone_conf_file = '/home/user/tmp/rclone.conf'

# Open the rclone.conf file
with open(rclone_conf_file, 'r') as f:
    # Read the file into a list of lines
    lines = f.readlines()

# Iterate over the <a> tags in the HTML
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    # Get the text of the <a> tag (e.g. "Hindi Movies")
    section_name = a.text.strip().lower()

    # Check if the section name exists in the rclone.conf file
    if any(section_name in line.lower() for line in lines):
        # Get the URL of the <a> tag
        new_url = a['href']

        # Use a regular expression to match the URL in the rclone.conf file
        regex = r'^(\[%s\]\n.*\n.*http.*)' % re.escape(section_name)

        # Update the URL in the rclone.conf file
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if section_name in line.lower():
                print(lines[i])  # <-- Add this line
                lines[i] = re.sub(regex, r'\1', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace(lines[i].split()[2], new_url)

# Open the rclone.conf file for writing
with open(rclone_conf_file, 'w') as f:
    # Write the updated lines to the file
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

The error it's showing:

```
File "/home/plex/tmp/script.py", line 37, in <module>
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(lines[i].split()[2], new_url)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Have A Octotastic Day !!

Comment: How does your HTML file get changed or generated? Maybe it would be easier to modify a source file in a format that can be parsed easily and generate both the HTML file and the configuration file. How do the section names in `rclone.conf` correspond to the HTML data? Please [edit] your to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Correction: "...[edit] your question to add requested information..."

Comment: I've edited it as you requested. I've typed the section names in rclone.conf mistakenly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So, what do you have so far? Which part of this is giving you trouble? This isn't a free script writing service, but we are happy to _help_ with your script. Please  show us what you have written so far and explain what you still need help with.

Comment: In addition to fixing obvious errors you should explain in your text how the values in your `rclone.conf` correspond to the HTML input. Are there any other links in the HTML document? What specific text pattern can be used to recognize the links that should be written to `rclone.conf`? Note that your question is not specifically related to Ubuntu but about general text processing or HTML parsing. It might better fit on https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I've added a dirty script & a regex but don't really know how to make them work together.

Comment: I would advice to use python for this: do a split on "<li>" and you almost have an array with the 2 items per category you need You can also automate fetching the html

Comment: @Rinzwind I've no knowledge about python !

Comment: basic python takes about 2 hours to learn ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I've added a python script to my post. Made this script using a friend's help but it showed an error mentioned in the post. Can you help me to solve the issue ?

Comment: line 35/36 do a print(lines[i]) and it will not show 2 spaces so it errors out on the [2] ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I've done changes as you recommended but now it shows a new error !!